# How to create a Gson library for Eclipse version Photon Release(4.8.0)

Tags: eclipse, gson

I am trying to follow the instructions here:  [medium article](https://medium.com/programmers-blockchain/importing-gson-into-eclipse-ec8cf678ad52)

But in Eclipse Photon Release 4.8.0, there is no User Libraries under Build Path:

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a workaround or should I install a different version of Eclipse?  If so, which one for Ubuntu Bionic Beaver?

Comment: You don't appear to have expanded the 'Build Path' tree in that picture - User Libraries in in a child entry in the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the Build Path to see the User Libraries section, as you can see here:

[image]